# G lim exists but G'(1) does not

Tags: real-analysis

> Find a function $G$ such that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{G(1+h)-G(1-h)}{2h}$ exists but $G'(1)$ does not.
>
> Find a function $G$ such that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{G(1+h)-G(1-h)}{2h}$ does not exist.

It is my understanding that when $x=1$ then $G'(1)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{G(1+h)-G(1-h)}{2h}$. Then wouldn't these two questions be asking for the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

The first question is asking for

- $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{G(1+h)-G(1-h)}{2h}$ exists (but $G'(1)$ does not exists).

The second question is asking for

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{G(1+h)-G(1-h)}{2h}$ **does not** exists

Hence the two questions are different.

We have $$G'(1) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{G(1+h) - G(1)}{h}$$

Hint for the first part, set $G(1)$ to be very different from the value around it.

Hint for the second one, looks for idea perhaps from translation of absolute value function.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative is often defined by

$$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{G(x+h)-G(x)}{h}.$$

If and only if $G$ is continuous at $x$ this is equivalent to $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{G(x+1)-G(x-1)}{2h}$. The limit you mentioned can exist when $G$ is not continuous at $1$, in which case $G'(1)$ need not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g(x) = |x-1|$

$\lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {g(1+h) - g(1-h)}{2h} = \lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {|h| - |-h|}{2h} = 0$

but

$g'(1) = \lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {g(h) - g(1)}{h}\\
 \lim_\limits{h\to 0^+} \frac {g(1+h) - g(1)}{h} \ne \lim_\limits{h\to 0^-} \frac {g(1+h) - g(1)}{h}$